# How to set keybindings to execute Python files in Neovim using the built-in terminal?

Tags: python, linux, lua, neovim

I started Neovim and downloaded LunarVim. The only LunarVim feature I'll use is the key `<M-1>` for opening the terminal.

So let's assume I'm working on Python file, and if I press `<F7>`, it automatically opens the terminal by `<M-1>` and types `python3 (file name).py` and executes it to get the result. I tried a lot but failed to find appropriate methods to use in my Lua configuration so I need some help.

Comment: I'm commenting to leave this thread I found in the VI/Vim Stack Exchange community - https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/15431 for whoever it might help in the future!

Answer (score 3):

First, to address the question title, here is a general Neovim solution.

I'd recommend adding the following code to your `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/python.lua` file (create this directory and file if it doesn't already exist). This file is sourced by Neovim whenever a `.py` file is loaded into a buffer.

The code below maps `Alt`+`r` to run the `run_curr_python_file` function. This function gets the current file name, opens the terminal within Neovim, and then types the command to run the Python file. Once complete, you can exit "terminal mode" via `Ctrl`+`\` and then `Ctrl`+`n`. Then you can quit `:q` (close) the buffer/window that holds the terminal's contents as normal.

```lua
local function run_curr_python_file()
    -- Get file name in the current buffer
    local file_name = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)

    -- Get terminal codes for running python file
    -- ("i" to enter insert before typing rest of the command)
    local py_cmd = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("ipython \"" .. file_name .. "\"<cr>", true, false, true)

    -- Determine terminal window split and launch terminal
    local percent_of_win = 0.4
    local curr_win_height = vim.api.nvim_win_get_height(0) -- Current window height
    local term_height = math.floor(curr_win_height * percent_of_win) -- Terminal height
    vim.cmd(":below " .. term_height .. "split | term") -- Launch terminal (horizontal split)

    -- Press keys to run python command on current file
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(py_cmd, "t", false)
end

vim.keymap.set({'n'}, '<A-r>', '', { 
    desc = "Run .py file via Neovim built-in terminal", 
    callback = run_curr_python_file
})
```

Now, in your case, LunarVim [makes use of](https://github.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/blob/master/lua/lvim/core/terminal.lua#L101) [`toggleterm`](https://github.com/akinsho/toggleterm.nvim) which I believe is launched via `<C-\>` (control + backslash) per the [`terminal.lua`](https://github.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/blob/master/lua/lvim/core/terminal.lua#L10) file. Thus, all you (should) have to do is modify the above `run_curr_python_file` function to press the necessary keys to launch toggleterm via the LunarVim mapping, and then type the command to run. In your case, you want to use `M-1` to launch the terminal. Here is an example (but note that I am unable to test whether this works as I don't use LunarVim):

```lua
local function run_curr_python_file()
    -- Get file name in the current buffer
    local file_name = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)

    -- Get terminal codes for running python file
    local py_cmd = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("python \"" .. file_name .. "\"<cr>", true, false, true)

    -- Get terminal codes for key-press sequence to launch toggleterm in LunarVim
    -- (one may have to use <C-\\> for Ctrl + backslash)
    local lnrvim_togterm_cmd = vim.api.nvim_replace_termcodes("<M-1>", true, false, true)

    -- Press keys to launch toggleterm in LunarVim
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(lnrvim_togterm_cmd, "m", true)

    -- Press keys to run python command on current file
    vim.api.nvim_feedkeys(py_cmd, "t", false)
end

vim.keymap.set({'n'}, '<A-r>', '', { 
    desc = "Run .py file via toggle term", 
    callback = run_curr_python_file
})
```